# Morris charts are not working with dynamic data, even after sending data in Json format

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I am using Morris graphs in my website, but when I am sending data in JSON format dynamically, then it is not working. But at the same time, if I push data manually, its starts working.
Please suggest some suggestion.

Here is the code

```js
function generateUserGraph() {  
            // some logic and below object is return  
            var toreturn = "{ Y: '10000001', A: '-1' }, { Y: '10000045', A: '1' }";
            return toreturn;
        }

        Morris.Bar({
            element: 'NLcurrentProgressBar',
            resize: true,
            data: [generateUserGraph()],
            barColors: function (row, series, type) {
                if (row.y == 0) {
                    return ['#6D5858'];
                }
                else if (row.y < 0) {
                    return ['#E71717'];
                }
                else {
                    return ['#00a65a'];
                }
            },
            xkey: ['Y'],
            ykeys: ['A'],
            labels: ['<a href="www.google.com">Question</a>'],
            hideHover: 'auto'
        });
```

```html
<div id = "NLcurrentProgressBar"></div>
```

Please suggest on the above code. If I directly pass the above string then it works but when I pass it using a function then no result renders

```html
like : below code is working :
data: [{ Y: '10000001', A: '-1' }, { Y: '10000045', A: '1' }],
```

```html
but this is not working :
data: [generateUserGraph()]
```

Comment: Unless you show a minimal example of the code you have that doesn't work, nobody here will be able to help you.

Comment: `data: { Y: '10000001', A: '-1' }, { Y: '10000045', A: '1' }` really work?

Comment: Yes, it is working...let me try to provide some sample of it at jsfiddle.

Comment: `data: { Y: '10000001', A: '-1' }, { Y: '10000045', A: '1' }` means: `data: { Y: '10000001', A: '-1' }` because next object is another element. This should be better: data: `[{ Y: '10000001', A: '-1' }, { Y: '10000045', A: '1' }]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide array of objects, but your function return string!

```
    function generateUserGraph() {  
        // some logic and below object is return  
        var toreturn = [{ Y: '10000001', A: '-1' }, { Y: '10000045', A: '1' }];
        return toreturn;
    }

    Morris.Bar({
        element: 'NLcurrentProgressBar',
        resize: true,
        data: generateUserGraph(),
        barColors: function (row, series, type) {
            if (row.y == 0) {
                return ['#6D5858'];
            }
            else if (row.y < 0) {
                return ['#E71717'];
            }
            else {
                return ['#00a65a'];
            }
        },
        xkey: ['Y'],
        ykeys: ['A'],
        labels: ['<a href="www.google.com">Question</a>'],
        hideHover: 'auto'
    });
```

Comment: Hi, even this is not working, it is still considering it as String. Please suggest how to convert it in correct format.

Comment: Hi Krzysiek, string is converted to object :).. but actually I am creating "toreturn" string dynamically after concatenating various strings by using some values in localStorage, and thats why I returned a string. Please help me in such situation in which I am preparing data from localStorage, is there some alternative way out, may be I am going in wrong direction. Please suggest.

Comment: "string is converted to object"? No there is not, unless you do it by yourself (but not in this code). `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` for store and restore data from `localStorage` and then operate like on every object. [working example](http://jsbin.com/yuvekuvuduwo/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I was sending string not the object and to resolve this issue. We need to push data in object format.

**[Working Link](http://jsbin.com/yuvekuvuduwo/1/edit)**